# Setting environment variables in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

For example, building a client for an API, like Twitch.

In a Dart CLI binary, I could use a generic environment variable, or a Dart definition variable. For example, using both as fallbacks:

```
main() {
  String clientId = 
      // dart -dCLIENT_ID='abc bin/example.dart
      // This is considered "compiled-into" the application.
      const String.fromEnvironment('CLIENT_ID') ??

      // CLIENT_ID='abc' dart bin/example.dart
      // This is considered a runtime flag.
      Platform.environment['CLIENT_ID'];

  // Use clientId.
}
```

Does Flutter have a way of setting either/both of these, specifically...

- During dev time
- When shipped to prod

Happy to help with some docs once I figure out how :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438564/how-do-i-build-different-versions-of-my-flutter-app-for-qa-dev-prod

Answer (score 162):

Starting from Flutter 1.17 you can define compile-time variables if you want to.

To do so just use `--dart-define` argument during `flutter run` or `flutter build`

If you need to pass multiple key-value pairs, just define `--dart-define` multiple times:

```sh
flutter run --dart-define=SOME_VAR=SOME_VALUE --dart-define=OTHER_VAR=OTHER_VALUE
```

and then, anywhere in your code you can use them like:

```dart
const SOME_VAR = String.fromEnvironment('SOME_VAR', defaultValue: 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE');
const OTHER_VAR = String.fromEnvironment('OTHER_VAR', defaultValue: 'OTHER_DEFAULT_VALUE');
```

Also, they can be used in native layers too.

[Here is an article that explains more.](https://medium.com/@tatsu.ukraine/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d)

Comment: To pass multiple key-value pairs, you can use also this syntax: `--dart-define=FIRST_VAR=first_value,SECOND_VAR=second_value` (using the comma, without repeat `--dart-define=`)

Comment: Is it possible to access this environment variables inside the AppDelegate.swift?

Comment: @JoseTapizquent I haven't tried, but I can assume that you can always add your dart define value to the plist file and read from there

Comment: @JoseTapizquent Yes you can. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59590990/1843853

Comment: Be aware the `const` is a requirement! see the article in the answer and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55870 I was having trouble getting this working since I didn't realize that

Comment: On, MacBook Air (M1, 2020) with flutter env as vars, this doesn't work. Flutter 2.0.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1d9032c7e1 (5 months ago) • 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
Engine • revision 05e680e202
Tools • Dart 2.12.3

Comment: How would you bake these environment variables into your app when building for production? e.g. --dart-define=ENVIRONMENT=PROD

Comment: You can specify them during any build command execution. If you have a CI/CD configured on bitrise or codemagic, just add them to the command arguments

Comment: setting multiple env variables using comma separated approach did not work. `flutter build web --dart-define=env=dev,domain=xyz` - this did not work.

Comment: I love how the question is: Setting environment variables in Flutter, yet all answers just point how to set --dart-define, WHICH ARE NOT ENV variables in the classical sense. If you use some FFI they will not see those env variables....

Answer (score 35):

For configuration a common pattern I've seen is to use separate main files instead. i.e.

`flutter run -t lib/production_main.dart`

and

`flutter build apk -t lib/debug_main.dart`

And then in those different main files set up the configurations desired.

In terms of reading ids, you can do that from arbitrary assets https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/.

I believe it is possible in Flutter to read from the environment as you suggest, however I don't know how to set those environment variables on iOS or Android.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I've put together a sample app demonstrating how this can be done [https://github.com/ROTGP/flutter_environments](https://github.com/ROTGP/flutter_environments)

Answer (score 31):

Since I was trying to solve this as well and encountered this thread I just wanted to add this for people looking for a solution in the future... If all you're looking for is PROD/DEV environments there is now a supported way of getting if the app is in production or not:

```
const bool isProduction = bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product');
```

As suggested by:

https://twitter.com/FlutterDev/status/1048278525432791041

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4014

Answer (score 16):

### To run your app (in `flutter run`)

- `flutter run --dart-define=EXAMPLE_API_ENDPOINT=https://api.example.com/`

### To release your app (in `flutter build`)

My app wasn't letting users log in I realized that environment variables were empty strings in the app, instead of their actual values .

- **iOS:** `flutter build ipa --dart-define=EXAMPLE_API_ENDPOINT=https://api.example.com/`
- **Android:** `flutter build apk --dart-define=EXAMPLE_API_ENDPOINT=https://api.example.com/`

### `--dart-define` documentation

From the `flutter run --help` or `flutter build ipa --help`, the `--dart-define` shows:

```
Additional key-value pairs that will be available as 
constants from the String.fromEnvironment, bool.fromEnvironment, 
int.fromEnvironment, and double.fromEnvironment constructors. 
Multiple defines can be passed by repeating "--dart-define" 
multiple times.
```

Comment: Please note: This is not a secure way in case you want to store api keys. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69349448/14119471)

Comment: It depends in what context. This doesn't "store" API keys, in CI you would pass the same variables which can be masked/hidden/protected. However, If someone hacked your app, they can extract the API key. You certainly don't want to put a powerful API key in your app.

Comment: You shouldn't have valuable API keys on your app. It should be used on your server if you need to use 3rd party services (when they give you a powerful API key). Your apps would authenticate with your server and your **server makes requests on behalf of the client apps**. This allows you to authenticate, authorize and rate-limit abusive clients.

Comment: @Binozo Regardless of how you pass API keys to the client... from a security point of view it is a hostile environment that you don't have control over.

Answer (score 13):

I use simple shell script to generate dart defines. In my app there are 3 build flavors: `dev`, `staging` and `prod`. Environment variables were defined in a regular `.env` file.

```
env/
├── dev.env
├── prod.env
└── staging.env
```

Here is the script to generate `dart-defines` from `.env` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# scripts/generate_dart_defines.sh

case "$1" in
"dev") INPUT="env/dev.env"
;;
"staging") INPUT="env/staging.env"
;;
"prod") INPUT="env/prod.env"
;;
*)
  echo "Missing arguments [dev|staging|prod]"
  exit 1
;;
esac

while IFS= read -r line
do
  DART_DEFINES="$DART_DEFINES--dart-define=$line "
done < "$INPUT"
echo "$DART_DEFINES"
```

Here is the script to trigger a build.

```
#!/bin/bash

# build.sh

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ] || [ -z "$3" ]; then
  echo -e "Missing arguments: [apk|appbundle|ios] [release|debug|profile] [dev|staging|prod]"
  # invalid arguments
  exit 128
fi

DART_DEFINES=$(scripts/generate_dart_defines.sh $3)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo -e "Failed to generate dart defines"
  exit 1
fi

echo -e "artifact: $1, type: $2, flavor: $3\n"
echo -e "DART_DEFINES: $DART_DEFINES\n"

eval "flutter build $1 --$2 --flavor $3 $DART_DEFINES"
```

The script accepts 3 arguments. First one is the artifact `apk`, `appbundle` or `ios`. Second one is the build type `release`, `debug` or `profile`. Third one is the build flavor, `dev`, `staging` or `prod`.

```
./build.sh apk release prod
```

Please note that you also required to configure android and ios for different build flavors separately.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

https://shockoe.com/ideas/development/how-to-setup-configurations-and-schemes-in-xcode/

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ManagingSchemes.html

Comment: How to use flutter attach and also use breakpoints for debugging using this approach? @udarawanasinghe

Comment: Can you please provide an example of .env file

Answer (score 13):

If you have multiple environment variables, use option `--dart-define-from-file=env.json`.

Ex:

```
flutter build web --dart-define-from-file=env.json
```

or

```
flutter run --dart-define-from-file=env_dev.json
```

Place env.json in the root, where pubspec.yaml resides.

Sample json files

1. env.json

   {
   "backend_url": "https://server.com"
   }
2. env_dev.json

   {
   "backend_url": "https://dev.server.com"
   }

Sample use:

```
const backendUrl = String.fromEnvironment('backend_url', defaultValue: 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE');
```

Comment: This does not work really anymore, see this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138793

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the **Flutter version >= 3.7** you can pass the environment variables in 2 ways either by argument or by a config file. for example:

```
flutter run --dart-define=BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Or you can create a file such as env.json and set your all desired variables in it for example:

```
{
  "BASE_URL": "http://localhost:3000",
  "TEST_USER": "test_user"
}
```

and then pass the file:

```
flutter run --dart-define-from-file=env.json
```

**And if your Flutter version is < 3.7 you have only the first option**

Answer (score 7):

I do `agree` with the answer posted by @tatsuDn **but I wanted to provide a solution that loads your environment variables from a .env file**.

First create a `.env` file in the root folder of your project.
Ensure that you add the file to your `pubspec.yaml` and `[git] ignore` it.

Here is how your `.env` file should look

```
API_KEY=sampleapikey
# This line is a comment

# The white line above will be ignored
HEADER=sampleapiheader
ANOTHER_UNIQUE_KEY=theValueOfThisKey
KEY_CONTAINS_#=*234*5#
KEY_CONTAINS_EQUALS=IP8iwe=0&
```

Here is how your assets section to look like.

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
  - assets/images/
  - assets/flags/
  - .env
```

Finally, **load** your environment variable by reading and parsing the `.env` file to get a `Map<String, String>` that contains your key value pairs.

```
Future<Map<String, String>> parseStringToMap({String assetsFileName = '.env'}) async {
  final lines = await rootBundle.loadString(assetsFileName);
  Map<String, String> environment = {};
  for (String line in lines.split('\n')) {
    line = line.trim();
    if (line.contains('=') //Set Key Value Pairs on lines separated by =
        &&
        !line.startsWith(RegExp(r'=|#'))) {
      //No need to add emty keys and remove comments
      List<String> contents = line.split('=');
      environment[contents[0]] = contents.sublist(1).join('=');
    }
  }
  return environment;
}
```

You can put a quick button in your code to test that the environment variables are being loaded properly.

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      final env = await parseStringToMap(assetsFileName: '.env');
      print(env);
    },
    child: Text('Print Environment Variables')
),
```

Here is the output from the .env file above.

```
>>>I/flutter ( 7182): {API_KEY: sampleapikey, HEADER: sampleapiheader, ANOTHER_UNIQUE_KEY: theValueOfThisKey, KEY_CONTAINS_#: *234*5#, KEY_CONTAINS_EQUALS: IP8iwe=0&}
```

Notes: You will need to rerun the app (not hot reload) so that the `.env` assets is loaded.
You can also just load your variables in a json file[this may be helpful when you have non string environemental variables and you dont want to parse string.
To avaoid IO, it is a good Idea to just **load the environment variables once and access them through out the app using service locators like `GetIt`**.

Comment: you can also use the flutter_dotenv library from pub.dev:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv

Comment: Thanks @Samuel Nde, but how are you going to change the API Key in production without affect app version or build process

Comment: @DanfordKija this solution will load whatever you put in your `.env`. So if you want different values for production and dev environments, the way to do it will be `to have a different .env file for production and testing environments respectively.`

Answer (score 5):

Flutter introduced environment variables at compile-time using the `--dart-define` argument. Where you have more than one environment variable, using the `--dart-define-from-file` argument is advisable.

For a single environment variable, follow the below:

```
flutter run --dart-define=VAR_NAME=SOME_VALUE
```

Where there is more than one environment variable, follow the below steps:

- Create a JSON file containing the variables.

```json
{
    "VAR_A": someValue,
    "VAR_B": anotherValue
}
```

- pass this file to the flutter build/run command

```
flutter run --dart-define-from-file=config.json
```

where config.json is the created JSON file containing the variables.

To retrieve these variables from your code, any of the following works depending on the data type:

```dart
const VAR_A = String.fromEnvironment('VAR_A', defaultValue: 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE');
const VAR_B = int.fromEnvironment('VAR_B', defaultValue: 1);
const VAR_C = bool.fromEnvironment('VAR_C', defaultValue: false);
```

It should be noted that there are no fromEnvironment constructors for double. The above arguments can also be used with the `flutter build` command.

The article [here](https://itnext.io/secure-your-flutter-project-the-right-way-to-set-environment-variables-with-compile-time-variables-67c3163ff9f4) explains how to do this in-depth.

Answer (score 0):

although above answers are correct coming from python and reactjs I used dotenv and found the same for flutter to load .env file
https://pub.dev/packages/dotenv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Create a class:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class AppUtils {
  static String get clientId {
    if (kDebugMode) return 'debug_id';
    else if (kProfileMode) return 'profile_id';
    else if (kReleaseMode) return 'production_id';
    else if (kIsWeb) return 'web_mode_id';
    
    throw ArgumentError('No mode detected');
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var id = AppUtils.clientId;
```

Comment: I think this is a clean answer generally, but at least for me it won't fit my use case. In my case I want to show and detect Crashlytics errors during automated testing. So I want to use a flag to display exceptions that would be logged visually for debug mode in a CI/CD automated test pipeline so that the error can be detected during a test easily (logs cannot be as easily read via Appium). So I have multiple running environments for, say, debug mode.

Comment: @RoboBear I definitely agree with you, it's not suitable in such cases.