# Flutter Driver - can we pass command line arguments to flutter driver tests

Tags: command-line-arguments, flutterdriver

I want to pass the test environment as a command line argument to my flutter driver integration test.
Is it possible ?

I did read in the below post that we can use environment variables in flutter driver tests.But I was more interested in command line arguments.

[How to pass an environment variable to a flutter driver test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475450/how-to-pass-an-environment-variable-to-a-flutter-driver-test)

Comment: Hi, Did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

**How to Pass Arguments to Test App?**

Whilst command line arguments are not supported in the traditional console command sense, you can use `--dart-define` to pass variables to the main test class. (Although if you are testing a desktop platform you can use the `-a` argument to Flutter Driver)

Under the covers it uses environment variables to pass arguments in.

See [How do you pass arguments from command line to main in Flutter/Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55004516/556600) for more details.

**How to Pass Arguments to Each Test?**

From within the test, the environment variables are not available, so we can use the DataHandler of the [Flutter Driver Extension](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver_extension/enableFlutterDriverExtension.html) to get the data.

In your main test app, the one that Flutter Driver uses to start the test, you can set up a DataHandler, like this:

```
void main() async {
  const testsString = String.fromEnvironment("tests");

  enableFlutterDriverExtension(handler: (request) async {
    String returnString;
    switch (request) {
      case "get_tests":
        {
          returnString = testsString;
          break;
        }
    }
    return returnString;
  });

  // Call main app
  app.e2e(configName: 'server-1');
}
```

Now, from your individual tests, you can call the DataHandler and request the 'command arguments' as data:

```
// A test file
void main() async {
  // Connect to app
  FlutterDriver driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  String testsString = await config.driver.requestData("get_tests");
  print("Args: $testsString");
}
```

Kick off the tests like this:

```
flutter drive --profile  --target ./test_driver/app.dart  --dart-define="tests=home_page" --dart-define="sample_data=ABC;XYZ"
```