# How do I build different versions of my Flutter app for qa/dev/prod?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a Flutter app, and I have variables with different values for different environments (QA, dev, prod, etc). What's a good way to organize my app so I can easily make a build for QA, dev, prod, and other environments?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way to do it: create different `main_<environment>.dart` files in the `lib/` directory of your project.

Each `main_<environment>.dart` contains the environment-specific configurations/values (such as the different database names, etc). Each `main_<environment>.dart` then imports the actual application library and runs the application, passing in the environment's values/configurations.

Then, choose which `.dart` file to build: `flutter run -t lib/main_debug.dart`

Comment: I believe that will only work when developing, the native sides that use `FlutterView` still use `runFromBundle` with "main".

https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/app/FlutterActivityDelegate.java#L177

Comment: @Simon maybe that problem is fixed by the build process e.g. `flutter build apk -t lib/main_debug.dart`?

Comment: @Jacob I committed a fix for it not working for iOS. I believe it's in the dev branch.

Comment: @Simon As you told, native sides (Android Studio in my case) not takes neither main_dev.dart nor main_prod.dart, it still running the "main" file, so How can I tell Android Studio which file run on Flutter side when pressing the "play" button?, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 47):

Building on Seth's idea, here's an example that sets up a global representing the `BuildEnvironment` named `env`.

**env.dart**

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

enum BuildFlavor { production, development, staging }

BuildEnvironment get env => _env;
BuildEnvironment _env;

class BuildEnvironment {
  /// The backend server.
  final String baseUrl;
  final BuildFlavor flavor;

  BuildEnvironment._init({this.flavor, this.baseUrl});

  /// Sets up the top-level [env] getter on the first call only.
  static void init({@required flavor, @required baseUrl}) =>
      _env ??= BuildEnvironment._init(flavor: flavor, baseUrl: baseUrl);
}
```

**main_dev.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'env.dart';
import 'app.dart';

void main() {
  BuildEnvironment.init(
      flavor: BuildFlavor.development, baseUrl: 'http://dev.example.com');
  assert(env != null);
  runApp(App());
}
```

**main_prod.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'env.dart';
import 'app.dart';

void main() {
  BuildEnvironment.init(
      flavor: BuildFlavor.production, baseUrl: 'http://example.com');
  assert(env != null);
  runApp(App());
}
```

- import `env.dart` to expose the `env` variable.
- run and build the app using the `target` option.

  `flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart
  flutter build -t lib/main_dev.dart`

To integrate with VS Code, define launch configurations:

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "development",
      "program": "lib/main_dev.dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart"
    },
    {
      "name": "production",
      "program": "lib/main_prod.dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart"
    }
  ]
}
```

I had originally set out to use command line arguments passed to Dart's `main` function, but I don't think args can currently be passed on the command line with `flutter run` or `flutter build`, although VS Code and Android Studio both support passing args to `main`. It also [seems](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15798) build flavor as a command line arg to `main` is not appropriate since args can be passed *after* the build process.

Comment: this should be marked as the right useful answer as one can change the additional run configs in the IDE to point to using this solution

Comment: How would you use this solution and keep your secret API keys and config settings out of source control?

Comment: Is there anyway you could do this solution and still have `flutter run` launch into Development mode by default? It's a bit annoying to add all the extra commands (`flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart`)

Comment: you're IDE may be able to handle that for you. The answer includes how to do it in VS Code.

Comment: Hello, is there a solution by using different Google Services (like Firebase) which requires different config for dev and release? It seems we cannot Google services change config file name.

Comment: @camillo777 [This article](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-use-different-google-services-json-file-with-multiple-product-flavors-android-7853d98dd6c0) explains it for Android, nothing Flutter specific.

Answer (score 27):

Release and debug mode can now be acquired using

```
const bool isProduction = bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product');
```

Because this is a constant it works with tree-shaking.
So code like

```
if(isProduction) {
  // branch 1
} else {
  // branch 2
}
```

would only include one of these two branches into production code depending on `isProduction`

Comment: This seems like a good solution, is there a reason it did not get more traction as the answer?

Comment: Perhaps because it's an older question and I just posted the answer 3 months ago.

Comment: If used all over the project, it may be prone to errors, in my opinion. Better use this only when initialising the application.

Comment: @droid8421 did you really downvote my answer because you think the code I suggestion should not be everywhere in your app??

Comment: This value is good, but still couldn't fulfill the question, since it's said `dev/qa/prod`.  This value only identify `dev/qa` or `prod`.

Answer (score 14):

Starting from Flutter 1.17 you can use `--dart-define` to build your app with different compile time variables. It works for both Dart and native layers. In dart you get these values with `String.fromEnvironment` for example. In that way you won't need to have tons or entry points and expose your environment credentials

Here is an article that explains more  https://link.medium.com/ibuTsWHrk6

Comment: This solution is great. The article shows how to create multiple builds for each environment and also makes the configuration MUCH easier on the iOS configuration side to produce multiple apps with the same code.

Comment: Okay that's something useful. But you missed the point of explaining how to handle "different values for different environments (QA, dev, prod, etc)".

Comment: @IvánYoed you can use dart defines to pass different values depends on the target environment. For example if you have bitrise or codemagic account, usually you going to have multiple workflows for multiple environments. There you can use env variables to pass needed

Answer (score 11):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

And use following const values:

```
if (kReleaseMode) {
  // App is running in release mode. 
} else if (kProfileMode) {
  // App is running in profile mode.
} else if (kDebugMode) {
  // App is running in debug mode.
} else if (kIsWeb) {
  // App is running on the web.
}
```

Comment: I strongly believe that one is the most simple and elegant solution for most cases.

Answer (score 5):

The cleaner way to do this is through **Build Flavors**.

As a quick example, if you want to have a different app id for your app for your "dev" build, you could have this in the gradle file:

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"
    }
}
```

Read more about gradle build variant configuration [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).

---

Now you can run with this build variant with command line:

```
flutter run --flavor dev
```

If you are using Android Studio, you can set the build variant in the Run configuration too:

[image]

Read more about iOS configuration on this [blog](https://medium.com/@matt.goodson.business/separating-build-environment-configurations-in-flutter-with-firebase-doing-it-the-right-way-c72c3ad3621f). And official flutter documentation about [build flavours](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors).

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can implement build variants.

In android:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug{
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
   qa{
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.qa
    }
}


productFlavors {

  dev {
      dimension "app"
      resValue "string", "app_name", "xyz Dev"
      applicationId "com.xyz.dev"
  }
  prod {
      dimension "app"
      resValue "string", "app_name", "xyz"
  }
}
```

In iOS :

add configuration by selecting project->runner-> configuration add one more

Comment: How you handle these environments in Flutter?

Comment: do we have something similar that appends .qa or .dev to the bundle identifier in iOS

Comment: @siva kumar but we cannot build through flutter `flutter build apk --qa`

Comment: @siva kumar what command are you using to generate "qa" apk version?

Comment: @SaahithyanVigneswaran flutter build apk --flavor qa

Answer (score 3):

Create a file at the root of the project `app_environment.dart`. Use the `kReleaseMode` variable from `foundation.dart` package to check for production mode.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class AppEnvironment {

  String getApiURL() {
    if (kReleaseMode) {
      return 'PROD_API_URL';
    } else {
      return 'STAGING_API_URL';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update July 2019 :

I wrote a Package that integrates the Flutter Global Config.

EZ Flutter is a collection of widgets, packages and many more usefull things, mixed up in little framework. The aim is to make standard features available from scratch.

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter

```
dependencies:
  ez_flutter: ^0.2.0
```

Check out the documentation how using different configurations works.

https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter/blob/master/documentation/APPLICATION_SETTINGS.md

++++ OLD ANSWER ++++

Additional information :

I had the same problem and used the solution suggested by Seth Ladd. Therefore I also needed different configuration for each app version (dev / prod ) and i don't want to write the configuration in the main_dev.dart or in the main_prod.dart file.

I wrote a simple flutter package that deals with having seperated configuration files and load them at app startup. The configuration is then available at each line of code in your app.

https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Flutter-Global-Config

How to use it :

Create a json file under assets/cfg/$file.json

Add assets/cfg to your pubspec.yaml

Loading different configuration files at app start :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:global_configuration/global_configuration.dart';

void main() async{
  await GlobalConfiguration().loadFromAsset("app_settings");
  await GlobalConfiguration().loadFromAsset("env_dev_settings");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
}
```

Using the configuration in your app :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:global_configuration/global_configuration.dart';

class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {

    CustomWiget(){
        // Access the config in the constructor
        print(GlobalConfiguration().getString("key1"); // prints value1
    }

    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // Access the config in the build method
        return new Text(GlobalConfiguration().getString("key2"));
     }
}
```