# How to disable all Logs [debugPrint()] in release build in flutter?

Tags: android, logging, flutter, debug-print

I have installed a release build apk in the android device but if I connect that device to Android studio then I am able to see all Logs/debugPrint statements.

Is there any way to disable the all the logs ?

Answer (score 16):

I combined the accepted answer with the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820431) and used it main.dart to silence all debugPrint everywhere.

```
const bool isProduction = bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product');
void main() {
  if (isProduction) {      
      // analyser does not like empty function body
      // debugPrint = (String message, {int wrapWidth}) {};
      // so i changed it to this:
      debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) => null;

  } 
  runApp(
    MyApp()
  );
}
```

Comment: The link you have given is not working. Getting page not found error.

Comment: i fixed the link. no idea what went wrong before :(

Comment: @Sebastian I think you always check the bool kDebugMode/kReleaseMode which is a constant provided by Flutter's foundation.

Comment: will compiler remove all calls for function which does nothing?

Comment: I know nothing about that, but it is mentioned here that it does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256139/performance-of-empty-function-on-dart

Answer (score 6):

You can assign a dummy function to the global `debugPrint` variable:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  debugPrint = (String message, {int wrapWidth}) {};
}
```

Comment: And how could I check the build variant so that I can do it only when I compile for production? I don't like this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438564/how-do-i-build-different-versions-of-my-flutter-app-for-qa-dev-prod and I don't wanna use package like simple_preprocessor.

Comment: I think the linked SO question us the way to go. You can also create a build script that modifies a source file before it calls `flutter build ...`

Comment: Dunno, but thanks. I’ll look forward this custom build script way. If you already have some links they’ll be appreciated ;)

Comment: You can use a simple shell script or a bash script. I have a project where I copy a different Dart file that contains some config values that are imported somewhere into place before building. This way I don't need to modify a files content

Comment: I’ll do some further research about this topic. Maybe I’ll post a specific question. For now upvoted your answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

With latest Flutter versions returning empty function does not work. Returning null is not recommended and should be avoided - if used, it is marked with tag that void functions should not have null return. Instead empty string will not cause any issue and works perfectly:

```
main() {
  debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) => '';
}
```