# Performance of empty function on Dart

Tags: performance, optimization, dart, flutter

Let say I have this code:

```
void test(){
 assert(() {
   print("This is Test");
 });
}
```

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592991/4894934), dart will remove `assert` on production build

but how about `test()` function which being called?

will this function be removed on build?

or will this have any significant impact on performance if I call empty function multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will optimize your code through inlining and removing calls to empty functions.

Comment: Thanks! could you add any references to this?

Comment: I don't have a reference but that's basic compiler optimization and I saw it mentioned in Dart GitHub issues.

Comment: I thought so too, but I was quite unsure as I haven't found any references related to Dart.

Will mark this as accepted answer for now. 
I'll be glad if anyone could add references to this

Comment: There are plans to improve docs and tools but not there yet https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33920#issuecomment-430211662

Comment: This video might provide some insight (haven't watched it myself yet) https://youtu.be/WjdrUphF5l4 but Vyacheslav did several talks about Dart compilation and optimizations already).

Answer (score 2):

> will this function be removed on build?

Not unless you use it only within other asserts. A typical example would be this:

```
assert(() {
  test();
  return true;
}());
```

If you *only* use it this way, then yes the function will be removed on build.

Comment: will there be any impact on release build performance if i called `test()` multiple times?