# How to publish 2 apps using 1 source code to Play store and App store?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to publish 2 clients to 1 source code. How do I do it?

I read this article.
[How do I build different versions of my Flutter app for qa/dev/prod?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47438564/8822337)

However I could not find the answer from this article.

Is it possible to publish 2 application in same source code and same Key file and same version code and same version name(com.eclipse.side)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order publish the same source code into 2 different applications, for example if you have a paid version and a free version of your application you need to use [flutter flavors](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors)
Basically, it will create 2 different applications that can be uploaded to the stores with the same code, with slight changes in the application Id for example

Comment: I used, https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ready-to-go-e59873f9d7de this article..**my question is, can to publish 2 application with same package name?**

Comment: The package name is a unique name to identify a specific app, when you are using flavors you are generating 2 different applications, each should have a unique package name, but why do you want to use the same package name?

Comment: we have 2 products on same code.. that's why we need.

Comment: then you can change the package name, each flavor should have its own package name

Answer (score 1):

> So, Is it possible to publish 2 application in same source code

Yes. It is irrelevant how you create your app.

> and same Key file

Yes, however it's not really recommended

> and same version code

Yes, version code is just a version number of your **specific** app only.

> and same version name(com.eclipse.side)

Yes, versionName  string used as the version number shown to users. Not sure you meant that one really as noone puts package id there though.

So the only thing that matters globally is application id from your manifest and it must be unique across **whole play store** submitted apps.

**EDIT**

> my question is, can to publish 2 application with same package name?**

Again, there's no such thing as **package name**. It's [application id](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) that matters **only**. All the other things are just labels. If you want to release two apps both can show "My App" label. But one mush have different application Id than other (i.e. `com.company.app1` and `com.company.app2`). That's it - so ensure your flavours set different application id and you should be good.

Comment: I used this method, https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ready-to-go-e59873f9d7de

Comment: how to build 2 apk