# Flutter : How to you execute code only in debug mode in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, debugging

I am using Flutter and I want to perform a specific task only in debug mode How I can execute code only in debug mode?

Answer (score 4):

Flutter provides `kDebugMode` which checks whether the app is running in debug mode or not. So you can execute the code just in the debug mode by just wrapping your desired code with the condition like this:

```
if (kDebugMode) {
  // your desired code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `assert` which only works in debug mode.

```dart
assert(() {
  // This block only runs in debug mode.

  return true;
}());
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64118075/6618622) also provides other ways of checking it.