# How to pass command line arguments like "-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled" to a flutter app

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to pass -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled flag to a flutter app when using `flutter run` on the command line?

I've added it to the scheme in XCode, so that when I run through XCode (by building and running the `Runner` scheme) the flag is passed, but when I run from the command line it doesn't get passed.

There does seem to be a `--flavor` command line flag for `flutter run` which claims it would let me select a scheme to run, but passing `--flavor=Runner` results in an error saying the scheme isn't found.  I'm not sure how to use this flag or find docs for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250184/setting-environment-variables-in-flutter to pass values to Dart. That doesn't work to pass it to native code (Java,ObjectC).

Comment: See also https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36, https://cogitas.net/creating-flavors-of-a-flutter-app/, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11547, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11547

Answer (score 7):

Spent a lot of time on this. Basically currently after you add launch argument to XCode scheme there is no simple way to `flutter run` with these arguments, here is [the issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17043) related to this.

The workaround I used is to run the app from XCode.