# Hide Google Maps API key from source control in a Flutter app

Tags: android, ios, git, google-maps, flutter

To enable the Google Maps SDK you must update:
[android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter#android) for android, and
[ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter#android) for ios with your API key.

## The problem:

I don't want to check in my API key into source control.

Is there a way to hide this key with a `.env` file and `.gitignore`?

What is best practice here?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://medium.com/code-better/hiding-api-keys-from-your-android-repository-b23f5598b906) could help? Atleast for android, hiding it inside the gradle.properties file

Comment: Looks like that is probably the answer for android, then something similar in ios. I was hoping there would be a way to inject the key using dart, but ‍♂️

Comment: If your key is properly secured, why would you need to hide it? https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm not sure what you mean. That documentation says "Do not embed API keys directly in code." and "Use environment variables". My question is: How do you do that in a flutter project?

Comment: Right, they say that indeed. For web pages, you can't hide the key anyway. For mobile apps, there are restrictions that you should/must apply (package name, certificate, etc.). Makes sense to not want to see it in source control, but you should still be safe if it was publicly released for some reason. But sorry I can't tell you how to do that in flutter; not my area.

Comment: Maybe this [flutter academy](https://flutter-academy.com/build-flavors-environment-specific-configuration/) article can help

Answer (score 18):

You can set your api keys as environment variables which can be read during build on your local machine only. Create an env variable MAPS_API_KEY="your-key-here", then add these lines to 
[your-project]/android/app/build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [mapsApiKey: "$System.env.MAPS_API_KEY"]
    }
```

and then you can use the mapsApiKeys to pass your api keys in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="${mapsApiKey}"/>
```

For ios, add these to AppDelegate.m

```
NSString* mapsApiKey = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment[@"MAPS_API_KEY"];

[GMSServices provideAPIKey:mapsApiKey];
```

Comment: how do you create an env variable ?

Comment: you can create them from your terminal by typing `MAP_API_KEY=some-value` or `SOMEVARIABLE=some-value`

Comment: ok. that's what I did but wasn't sure. thx. also, when I build then depliy the app, there will be no way for anybody to see the key by decompiling my app? that's superbe !

Comment: I tried to follow this recipe on Windows using Powershell, `$Env:MAPS_API_KEY = "<api-key>"`, and get `API Key: null` when running in Android Studio.

Comment: I use linux so i dont know if thats how environment variable named MAPS_API_KEY is set in the powershell. Is that what you were trying to do ?

Comment: AppDelegate.m didnt exist this is my AppDelegate.swift 
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if let value = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["MAPS_API_KEY_IOS"] {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(value)
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

Comment: can you provide the swift code for ios, please? @Kushal Billaiya

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Flutter 1.17 you can use compile-time variables for this. Just use `--dart-define` key in `flutter run` or `flutter build` commands. Then you can use them in your iOS or Android code. [Here is an article](https://link.medium.com/ibuTsWHrk6) with some explanation and samples

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed answer? The link is for a Medium article that requires a subscription to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your keys in a separate file, and add that file to `.gitignore`. Then if you push your files to the repository, that file will be ignored.

In case you have a new colleague, who needs to start working on the same project, you will need to share this file with them. After checking out the project from the repository, they will need to place that file in the same directory as it was originally.

Answer (score 0):

I've been living with my Google Maps API key hardcoded in my Flutter app for iOS for a long time, but today I decided to solve it once and for all, but even after reading many articles and blogposts I didn't find a solution that is simple enough.

Then I thought that I can just read the API_KEY from `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in my `AppDelegate.swift`, like this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist") {
    let nsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        
    if let apiKey = nsDictionary?["API_KEY"] as? String {
        print("AppDelegate: API_KEY found")
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(apiKey)
    }
```

Comment: You are using your Firebase API key as a Google Maps API key ?

Comment: I don't remember :)