# Flutter: Build web app with file other than 'lib/main.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart

I use more than one `dart main` file in my lib folder for passing different app configuration depending on server each will use.

Example of main_dev.dart

```
void main() async {
  FlavorConfig(
    flavorName: 'test',
    values: {
      'BASE_URL': 'http://$MY_IP:9002/graphql',
      'WS_URL': 'ws://$MY_IP:9002/graphql',
    },
  );

  await runApp(ProviderApp());
}
```

For now I have `main_test.dart` and `main_live.dart` and  everything works fine when building android app.

Example I use the following command to build test app.

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./build/app/outputs/symbols lib/main_test.dart
```

Note the last part `lib/main_test.dart` I specify which file I intend to use and it works really well for building android app.

But I tried similar thing for web and I get the following error as it seems to me building web app needs `main.dart`.

> Target dart2js failed: Exception:
> .dart_tool/flutter_build/11c1feed0a867bb072ab6c7b64967a31/main.dart:8:8:
> Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': Error reading
> 'lib/main.dart'  (The system cannot find the file specified. ) import
> 'package:my_amazing_app/main.dart' as entrypoint;
> ^ .dart_tool/flutter_build/11c1feed0a867bb072ab6c7b64967a31/main.dart:13:3:
> Error: Method not found: 'main'.   entrypoint.main();   ^^^^ Error:
> Compilation failed.
>
> Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...
> 20.3s Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.

How can can specify the file I want in command for web too?.

I have tried the following without success `flutter build web lib/main_test.dart`

Comment: [Flutter web as of yet doesn't support flavors,](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59388) so the workaround seems to be to use Firebase build targets. Personally, I'd just use [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250184/setting-environment-variables-in-flutter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using different entrypoints, you can use compile-time constants. When running `flutter build`, you can pass in `--dart-define=foo=bar` to set a compile-time constant, and you can then use it from your code using:

```dart
const foo = String.fromEnvironment('foo');
print(foo);  // prints "bar"

const fooExists = bool.hasEnvironment('foo');
print(fooExists);  // prints "true"
```

Note that this is a `const` value, so the compiler can still use this information for tree shaking.

In your case, assuming you have 2 environments: `prod` and `test`, you could do something like this:

```dart
// lib/main.dart

void main() {
  const env = String.fromEnvironment('env');
  if (env == 'test') {
    runApp(TestApp());
  } else if (env == 'prod') {
    runApp(ProdApp());
  } else {
    throw 'unknown environment: $env';
  }
}
```

Then when you build your app, you can use:

```
flutter build web --dart-define=env=prod <other-args>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's useful. Any option to use dart env variables when building from XCode?

Answer (score 0):

User -t

flutter build web -t lib/main-test.dart

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**