# Are compile-time variables secure in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, security

I've got some sensitive data (api secret key) to store in the app on the client-side, I know this is a bad practice to store this kind of information but there are not feasible alternatives for now, I'm already tampering the problems that could arise if such key is leaked, but I wish to know if encoding such key in the build during compile time is secure or not, in case of decompiling the code, even if obfuscated, is it more difficult to retrive a compile-time variable?

Here an example of how I would use it

```
flutter build apk --dart-define=APP_VERSION=0.1.2 --dart-define=SECRET_KEY=123456
```

Comment: You can, at most, obfuscate it so that it doesn't show up in plain text. But if your program can read it (and it must, to use it), so can your attacker. Consider your key leaked as soon as you publish your program.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is precisely as insecure as any other approach.

### Create project that uses the define

(If the define isn't used, it'll be stripped out, but obviously you want to use it.)

```
void main() {
  const String key = String.fromEnvironment('SECRET_KEY');
  print(key);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

### Build

I'm using "SEKRET" here rather than "123456" because there are a lot of "123456" strings in a normal APK and it could give a false positive.

```
flutter build apk --dart-define=APP_VERSION=0.1.2 --dart-define=SECRET_KEY=SEKRET
```

### Open the APK

```
cd build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/
mkdir app
cd app
unzip ../app-release.apk
```

### Look for secret strings

```
strings lib/x86_64/libapp.so | grep SEKRET
> SEKRET
```

This is no different than just hardcoding the string into the app. There is no benefit to "hiding" it in a define, and there's no way to really secure this. The best you can do is obfuscate and hope the attacker isn't highly motivated. Or invest in ongoing obfuscation and hardening improvements every time they crack your system. (This is very difficult and expensive, and there is, by its nature, no universal or permenant solution.)

You cannot hide an API key in a binary. You cannot hide an API key that an app uses in memory. You cannot reliably keep secrets from someone who controls the hardware the app runs on and is motivated to find those secrets.

Comment: So basically there is no way to 100% protect these secrets from a motivated attacker?  Meaning if I am using GCP, I would need to monitor my GCP account and watch for a hacker using compute resources after hacking my Flutter app and getting the key?  Does GCP cover these types of losses?

Comment: You generally shouldn't have your app talk directly to a third-party service. You should have it authenticate to your own server, and then have that server talk to your third-party service. Then you maintain control. No service is going to offer a blanket forgiveness of fraud (though many services will negotiate with you to forgive some of the costs of some single large fraud event). If you send your key out in your app, it can be used. And in any case, you absolutely must monitor any service you're paying for or responsible for.

Comment: There is definitely an advantage to not having sensitive secrets checked into source control (e.g., git). And there are advantages to not using the same secrets for development and production. So any system that requires the developer/builder to locally provision secrets in a file (e.g., .env) that is .gitignore'd and installed into artifacts at build time is better than including secrets in source code. --dart-define provides a way to add the secrets to artifacts at build time so they do not need to be part of the source code.