# environment variables in FLutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a Flutter project with Google Maps. I have an API Key and as per the documentation we should not put it directly in the AndroidManifest.xml or build.grafle file.

I came accross this snippet of code in a github project and I cannot really understand it. I am not that good in gradle.

```
def dartEnvironmentVariables = []
   if (project.hasProperty('dart-defines')) {
       dartEnvironmentVariables = project.property('dart-defines')
          .split(',')
          .collectEntries { entry ->
             def pair = new String(entry.decodeBase64(), 'UTF-8').split('=')
             [(pair.first()): pair.last()]
    }
}
```

My question is, where should `dart-defines` be within the project structure. I couldn't find any in the github project.
And what could such a file look like?

I want to store the Goole Maps API KEY there such that I could use it in my build.gradle file as follows:

```
manifestPlaceholders.ANDROID_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = dartEnvironmentVariables.ANDROID_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEYs
```

And then in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${ANDROID_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61725261/18422887